# How do I get the correct result in the list of lists sorting in python

Tags: python

How do I sort the list below?

My results was:

```
['10','11','12','7','8','9'],['1','2','3','4','5','6']]
```

Here's my code

```
lst= [['7','10','8','9','11','12'],['3','1','2','4','6','5']]

for i in lst:
    i.sort()
    print(i)
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Just google how to sort list in python. ..you will find a lot of stuff about that topic

Comment: @BrianCain asks a perfectly reasonable question: what is wrong with the output you got? Seems to me like your were sorting strings and you got the expected output from sorting those strings. Nothing obvious worng with that. You'll have to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: think about it for a second, you got a list with 2 lists within it right? to access the first one you'd do `lst[0]` and to access the other `lst[1]`... I leave the rest for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are string objects, for string:

```
'10' < '7' because `1 < 7`
```

I think you want:

```
>>> [sorted(map(int, i)) for i in lst]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
>>>
```

Just covert them to int objects before sort.

---

If you need keep them in string object, covert them back or set a key:

```
>>> [list(map(str, i)) for i in [sorted(map(int, i)) for i in lst]]
[['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]

>>> [sorted(i, key=lambda x: int(x)) for i in lst]
[['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
```

Comment: This is  giving me: [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]  not  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]  thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted(list, key=int)`:

```
lst= [['7','10','8','9','11','12'],['3','1','2','4','6','5']]

for i in lst:
    i = sorted(i, key=int)
    print(i)
```

Comment: Fine, don't know that before :)